# Prove: $\forall x ( R(x,x) \to R(a,a))$

Tags: theorem-provers

Nãoconsigo entender como se prova este argumento, podem me ajudar: $\forall x ( R(x,x) \to R(a,a))$

*Translation:* I don't understand how to prove that

> $$\forall x ( R(x,x) \to R(a,a))$$

Could you help me?

Comment: It is not true in general. Do you have the brackets in the formula right?

Comment: Sim. A escrita da formula esta correta.

Answer (score 0):

What is true is that

$\forall x R(x,x) \to R(a,a)
$.

Just substitute $a$ for $x$ in the left side.